# How to save incoming data from serial port to a text file in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I have two buttons on my window.

1. By clicking the start button I want to open the port and
   see the data in the textbox and at the same time i want to save this data    in    Another empty text file line by line.
2. And by clicking the stop button the program just stops saving    the     data but still shows the incoming data from serial port in the textbox. Can someone help? My code for start and stop button looks like:

   ```
   private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       serialPort1.PortName = pp.get_text();
       string Brate = pp.get_rate();
       serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(Brate);

         serialPort1.Open();

       if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
       {
           buttonStart.Enabled = false;
           buttonStop.Enabled = true;
           textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
       }
   }


   private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {


       string Fname = pp.get_filename();
       System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Fname, this.textBox1.Text);


   }
   ```

Comment: ok, as it stands this isnt saving as it goes, its saving as you hit the stop button. You also dont show how textbox1 is being filled.. you just need the data arrival toggle saving to file while you do the stop...

Comment: Could you please give an example? I am new to c#. Thanks for the patience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You need to register to DataRecieved event of serial port to receive response from SerialPort instance.

```
sp = new SerialPort();
sp.DataReceived += sp_DataReceived;
```

Then, in sp_DataRecieved:

```
    void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this the read buffer
        byte[] buff = new byte[9600];
        int readByteCount = sp.BaseStream.Read(buff, 0, sp.BytesToRead);
        // you can specify other encodings, or use default
        string response = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff);

        // you need to implement AppendToFile ;)
        AppendToFile(String.Format("response :{0}",response));

        // Or, just send sp.ReadExisting();
        AppendToFile(sp.ReadExisting());
    }
```

2) You will receive data if there is still data in read buffer of SerialPort instance. After closing port, you need to deregister from DataReceived event.

```
sp -= sp_DataRecieved;
```

**UPDATE**

You can use this method to append to file

```
private void AppendToFile(string toAppend)
{
    string myFilePath = @"C:\Test.txt";
    File.AppendAllText(myFilePath, toAppend + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: `private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,  System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)                                        
                                                                                                                                          {
                      RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();                                   
                      this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
           
                     }`     My dataReceived event code

Comment: I can read the data from serial port and can show it in a textbox. But I need to save it at the same time in Another file. above is my dataRceived event handler.

Comment: in UPDATE you have shown the filepath. I want to just pass the file name, Because I have to save an empty file at run time. Also I dont know where to write the code in UPDATE. I mean I have to write it in the start button or stop?     Thanks for your patience

Comment: I think I have helped enough, you need to implement these codes yourself. Also, if you can't figure out where to put the snippets you need more practice and research. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you, please mark the answer as accepted so other users know it is a working solution.